# Are registers signed during a Convalidation ceremony

Tags: catholicism, marriage, canon-law, pentecostalism, weddings

My husband is Roman Catholic and I m Pentecostal. We married under a lot of pressure with no family members present.

After much strife our families have agreed
We have been trying to book a notice of marriage and are waiting for a reply.
We may have to opt for a Convalidation which would destroy our families again as they might find out what we felt we had to do.
We understand that a nuptial mass and a Convalidation are essentially the same
But are registers still signed in a Convalidation ceremony?

Comment: Without a source to affirm such as yes, I would believe that the answer would be in the affirmative. I will keep looking.

Comment: Convalidation and a nuptial Mass are not strictly mutually exclusive. One is specifically a process to "fix" a canonical defect with a marriage and one is the liturgical rite for contracting marriage. More germane to your question is there is precedence for a marriage that is not recorded in the normal way, but I don't recall the grounds for when it might be done